# Multiple tables show/hide refactor

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, hide, show

Let us say I have multiple tables that display specific information, how would I go about displaying the selected table but hiding the others, in the cleanest way possible.

I have come up with the below which works as intended, but definitely not the cleanest way of doing it I am sure.

I have considered a few other methods such as jQuery append and toggle but haven't been able to come up with a viable solution.

```
 <table id="table-1">
        <th>Table Heading</th>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Text</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <table id="table-2">
        <th>Table Heading</th>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="table3">
        <tr>
            <th>Table Heading</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Text</td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
```

jQuery

```
    $("#text-one").click(function () {
        $("#table-1").show();
        $("#table-2").hide();
        $("#table-3").hide();
    });

    $("#text-two").click(function () {
        $("#table-2").show();
        $("#table-1").hide();
        $("#table-3").hide();
    });

    $("#text-three").click(function () {
        $("#table-3").show();
        $("#table-1").hide();
        $("#table-2").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can persist the target in custom `data-*` prefixed attribute, which can be accessed using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Add a common class to `BUTTON` and `TABLE` elements, then [Class Selector `(".class")`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) can be used to bind event handler.

*HTML*

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-target="#table-1">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-target="#table-2">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-target="#table-3">Button 3</button>

<table class="table" id="table-1"></table>
<table class="table" id="table-2"></table>
<table class="table" id="table-3"></table>
```

*Script*

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    var targetSelector =$(this).data('target');
    var target = $(targetSelector);
    target.show();
    $(".table").not(target).hide();
});
```

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var targetSelector = $(this).data('target');
  var target = $(targetSelector);
  target.show();
  $(".table").not(target).hide();
});
```

```css
.table {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-target="#table-1">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-target="#table-2">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-target="#table-3">Button 3</button>

<table class="table" id="table-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Table Heading 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sample Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table" id="table-2">
  <tr>
    <th>Table Heading 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sample Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table" id="table-3">
  <tr>
    <th>Table Heading 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sample Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you very much! Always something to learn even when it comes to HTML and jQuery, which may appear simple to some but that is the beauty of it.